# Python Tkinder Button

Tags: python, servo, tkinter

i have a promblem with GUI Tkinter, when i click the button of my gui enviroment the arm of my robot dont response more specific  call the function but steal remaning in 0 degre``es from the other my code is fine because when i click from my keyboard 'w' my arm plus for each time i click the button 15 degrees. Really i dont know if i use the right button , i am beginner in the python and i need some advice. my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(15, 50)
pwm.start(0)
root = Tk ()
Label(root, text="ANgel").grid(row = 0)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
i = 0

def Angle(angle): 
   #Calculate 
   duty = angle / 18 + 2
   GPIO.output(15,True)
   pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
   time.sleep(0.3)
   GPIO.output(15, False)
   pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(0)



def servo_up(event):
   #Servo lifts arm 
   global i
   if event.keysym == 'w' and i < 180:
     key_press = event.char
     print "Key: ", event.char
     i = i + 15
     Angle(i)
     print " ", i
  else:
     print "You are in the limit: ", i, "Degrees"

 b1 = Button(root,text = 'quit', bg = "red", command = root.quit)
 b1.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

 b= Button(root, text="Arm Up")
 b.bind("<Button-1>", servo_up)
 b.grid(row=2, column = 1)

root.bind('<w>', servo_up)

root.mainloop()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

When i click the button from graphical enviroment, I'm getting:

```
You are in the limit:  0 Degrees
```

when i click the w from keyboard, it work:

```
Key:  w
     15
Key:  w
     30
Key:  w
     45
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like that if you click the button, you are still checking `if event.keysym == 'w'` so it is falling through to the `else:`

Comment: @JohnS Because of the way Stack Exchange works, please consider posting your observation as an answer so that Nikos Mitsiou can accpt it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that if you click the button, you are still checking if `event.keysym == 'w'` so it is falling through to the `else:`